# How to vertical text alignment for formattedtext?

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, formatted-text

is it possible to setting vertical text alignment  to formatted text in c#
for example
my formatted text is

```
 var formattedtext=new FormattedText("some string", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight, this.GetTypeface(), 12.0, Brushes.Black);
```

i need align the formatted text in vertical alignment center with in the particular rect region.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could achieve that.
My approach will also scale down to fit inside the bounding box in case text overflows limits.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Use to draw some text using font file location.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="font">Font file location</param>
    /// <param name="someText"></param>
    /// <param name="fontSize"></param>
    /// <param name="width">bitmap width</param>
    /// <param name="height">bitmap height</param>
    /// <returns>new instance of RenderTargetBitmap</returns>
    private static RenderTargetBitmap DrawText(string font, string someText, int fontSize, int width = 700, int height = 300)
    {
        var name = Path.GetFileName(font);
        var glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(font));
        string family = String.Join(" ", glyphTypeface.FamilyNames.Values.ToArray<string>());
        var style = glyphTypeface.Style;
        var weight = glyphTypeface.Weight;
        var fontStretch = glyphTypeface.Stretch;
        string fontUri = new Uri(font.Replace(name, ""), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute).AbsoluteUri + "/#" + family;
        var fontFamily = new FontFamily(fontUri);

        var typeface = new Typeface(fontFamily, style, weight, fontStretch);
        var formattedText = new FormattedText(someText, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            typeface, fontSize, 
            Brushes.Black);

        formattedText.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

        var drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

        RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(drawingVisual, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
        RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(drawingVisual, EdgeMode.Aliased);
        TextOptions.SetTextRenderingMode(drawingVisual, TextRenderingMode.Aliased);

        using (var drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
        {
            drawingContext.DrawRectangle(Brushes.White, null, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));

            var geometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));

            var bounds = geometry.Bounds;

            var sW = width / bounds.Width;
            var sH = height / bounds.Height;
            var ratio = sH <= sW ? sH : sW;

            if (ratio > 1) ratio = 1;

            var translateX = (width - bounds.Width * ratio) / 2;
            var translateY = (height - bounds.Height * ratio) / 2;
            var transformGroup = new TransformGroup();
            transformGroup.Children.Add(new ScaleTransform(ratio, ratio));
            transformGroup.Children.Add(new TranslateTransform(-bounds.X * ratio + translateX, -bounds.Y * ratio + translateY));

            geometry.Transform = transformGroup;

            drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Black, null, geometry);
        }

        var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
            width, height,
            0, 0,
            PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

        renderTargetBitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

        return renderTargetBitmap;
    }
```

Usage:

```
        //Setting System.Windows.Control.Image source
        image.Source = DrawText(@"C:\Windows\Fonts\ariali.ttf", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\nconsectetur adipisicing elit,\nsed do eiusmod tempor", 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
// e is the PaintEventArgs, which is passed as a parameter

// construct a new Rectangle .
Rectangle  displayRectangle = 
    new Rectangle (new Point(40, 40), new Size (80, 80));

// construct new StringFormat object
var format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionVertical);

// set the LineAlignment and Alignment properties for 
format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near;
format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

// draw the bounding rectangle and a string for the StringFormat object.
e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, displayRectangle);
e.Graphics.DrawString("Showing Format", this.Font, 
    Brushes.Red, (RectangleF)displayRectangle, format);
```

Comment: But i need to use DrawingContext.DrawText(formattedtext,new Point(40,40)) in WPF.i think above solution is not possible in my requirement(WPF). because i dont have the painting argument .

Comment: Yes, the answer is for WinForm's since you did not specify in your question or tags that it is WPF specific. As far as I know there is no option for this in WPF. Mostly people add a newline character after each character of your text to get it to display vertical.